# Trying to have my newsletter subscription confirmation page only accessible when user access it by confirmation email

Tags: php, .htaccess

Im doing a newsletter system.

I have a input type text where user writes his email and then click on submit to subscribe in newsletter.

After this, user will receive an email saying to confirm his subscription **he needs to click in a confirmation link** that I make available in received confirmation email.

And this link will redirect to my newsletter confirmation page where I do an update, to subscribe this user in my database table

**This is the redirecting link:**

```
http://localhost/website/newsletter/confirm/useremail@email.com/b443e5a143bb54b4313dfferef3
```

Everything is working fine, but I want that my newsletter subscription confirmation page is only acessible when user access the link from the confirmation received email.

I dont that user can acess this page "`http://localhost/website/newsletter/confirm/`", because this page dont have nothing to show, only have something to show if the user
 acess this page from  confirmation link, because this page will get the url variables (email and code) and do an update in my table and show a message "Subscription with sucess".

Do you know how can I do this?

**In my query string** Im trying to do this like this:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
$url = explode('/', $url);
$url[0] = ($url[0] == NULL ? 'index' : $url[0]);
$newsletter = 'newsletter';
$confirm = 'confirm';   
    if(file_exists('template/'.$url[0].'.php')){
         require_once('template/'.$url[0].'.php');
    }
    //here its what Im trying for this purpose
    elseif(file_exists('template/'.$newsletter.'/'.$confirm.'.php')){
          require_once('template/404.php');
    }
    elseif(file_exists('template/'.$url[0].'/'.$url[1].'/'.$url[2].'.php')){
         require_once('template/'.$url[0].'/'.$url[1].'/'.$url[2].'.php');

    }
    elseif(file_exists('template/'.$url[0].'/'.$url[1].'.php')){
         require_once('template/'.$url[0].'/'.$url[1].'.php');
    }

    else{
         require_once('template/404.php');
    }
}
```

But like this, Im always entering in my 404.php file, even when I acess from confirmation email link "`http://localhost/website/newsletter/confirm/useremail@email.com/b443e5a143bb54b4313dfferef3`".

And I want to include my 404.php file just when some user try to acess "`http://localhost/website/newsletter/confirm/`", 
when access is not done by confirmation link from email.

Do you know how can I do this?

Comment: Can't you just redirect/include your main newsletter page (eg. your home) inside your confirm.php if it detects variables missing / having wrong values? Or include/require your 404 page after checking for the variables?

Comment: Thanks ccKep. I solve the problem with your tip!